# request.body is empty when trying to send an image to server NodeJS. The body is form-data type

Tags: node.js, postman, koa

request.body is empty when trying to send an image to server NodeJS. The body is form-data type. I am using koa-bodyparser. I want simple just to print on the console the request.body but is always undefined. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: try `req.file` instead of `req.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved! Instead of using koa-bodyparser, i have used to following body parser:

```
   const bodyparser: any = require('koa-body');
   this.app.use(bodyparser({
            formidable:{
                uploadDir: './uploads',
                keepExtensions: true
            },
            multipart: true,
            strict: false, //allow application.json !
            urlencoded: true
        }));
```